# Exception Type: 00000020 and Crash thread 4 are related?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Actually this crash is not reproducing every time, even not frequently but we got this crash in our production app. I am not sure where is the problem. It is telling crash is happening in thread 4 in Environments class line number 38.

```
Code:

 NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
 NSString* envsPListPath = [bundle pathForResource:@"Environment" ofType:@"plist"];

Line 38:
NSDictionary *environments = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:envsPListPath];
```

But according to exception type:00000020 , app is failed to launch in in-time. 
I don't understand whats wrong with above code. Please help me out the relation b/w watchdog crash and above lines of code.

```
Crash Log: 

  Incident Identifier: FBDC0D68-9EC3-423C-A0DF-CD08EA079215
    Hardware Model:      iPod4,1
    Process:         Sparkle [16542]
    Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/55887817-5FD2-479A-B124-6ABF1907B339/Sparkle.app/Sparkle
    Identifier:      Sparkle
    Version:         ??? (???)
    Code Type:       ARM (Native)
    Parent Process:  launchd [1]

    Date/Time:       2013-10-26 14:30:43.046 -0400
    OS Version:      iOS 6.1.3 (10B329)
    Report Version:  104

    Exception Type:  00000020
    Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
    Highlighted Thread:  4

    Application Specific Information:
    com.xxxx.xxx failed to launch in time

    Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 15.060 (user 15.060, system 0.000), 50% CPU 
    Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 1.756, 6% CPU

    Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    Thread 0:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a106eb4 mach_msg_trap + 20
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a107048 mach_msg + 36
    2   UIKit                           0x33ebb7e6 _UIPasteboardServerCreate + 158
    3   UIKit                           0x33ebb684 UIPasteboardServerCreate + 208
    4   UIKit                           0x33ebb54a -[UIPasteboard(Static) _initWithName:system:create:] + 90
    5   UIKit                           0x34055d9c +[UIPasteboard pasteboardWithName:create:] + 292
    6   Sparkle                         0x0049fe8a -[ADMS_Churn readFacebookReferrer] + 42
    7   Sparkle                         0x0049f5ac -[ADMS_Churn setInstallVariables] + 204
    8   Sparkle                         0x0049f2b0 -[ADMS_Churn setLaunchTypeVariables] + 68
    9   Sparkle                         0x0049ead4 -[ADMS_Churn trackSessionStart] + 40
    10  Sparkle                         0x0049ea56 -[ADMS_Churn resumeSession] + 46
    11  Sparkle                         0x004a7ae4 -[ADMS_NotificationHandler handleApplicationNotifications:] + 112
    12  CoreFoundation                  0x31eec034 _CFXNotificationPost + 1424
    13  Foundation                      0x32802594 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 68
    14  UIKit                           0x33e03896 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1754
    15  UIKit                           0x33dfb846 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 694
    16  UIKit                           0x33da3c34 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1000
    17  UIKit                           0x33da36c8 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 68
    18  UIKit                           0x33da3116 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6150
    19  GraphicsServices                0x35a955a0 _PurpleEventCallback + 588
    20  GraphicsServices                0x35a951ce PurpleEventCallback + 30
    21  CoreFoundation                  0x31f70170 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 32
    22  CoreFoundation                  0x31f70112 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
    23  CoreFoundation                  0x31f6ef94 __CFRunLoopRun + 1380
    24  CoreFoundation                  0x31ee1eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
    25  CoreFoundation                  0x31ee1d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
    26  UIKit                           0x33dfa480 -[UIApplication _run] + 664
    27  UIKit                           0x33df72fc UIApplicationMain + 1116
    28  Sparkle                         0x003fafd2 main (main.m:18)
    29  libdyld.dylib                   0x3a050b1c start + 0

    Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
    Thread 1:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a107648 kevent64 + 24
    1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a0404ec _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 792
    2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a032df4 _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$up + 32

    Thread 2:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a117d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
    1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a065cf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a065a12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
    3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a0658a0 start_wqthread + 4

    Thread 3 name:  WebThread
    Thread 3:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a106eb4 mach_msg_trap + 20
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a107048 mach_msg + 36
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x31f70040 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 124
    3   CoreFoundation                  0x31f6ed9e __CFRunLoopRun + 878
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x31ee1eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
    5   CoreFoundation                  0x31ee1d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
    6   WebCore                         0x37ecf500 RunWebThread(void*) + 440
    7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a07030e _pthread_start + 306
    8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a0701d4 thread_start + 4

    Thread 4 name:  Dispatch queue: momentumMapQueue
    Thread 4:
    0   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a060332 szone_malloc_should_clear + 110
    1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a060290 malloc_zone_malloc + 68
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x31eda712 _CFRuntimeCreateInstance + 210
    3   CoreFoundation                  0x31f7953a __CFStringCreateImmutableFunnel3 + 1882
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x31edd6c6 CFStringCreateWithBytes + 46
    5   CoreFoundation                  0x31effe76 _uniqueStringForUTF8Bytes + 90
    6   CoreFoundation                  0x31effd40 parseStringTag + 1304
    7   CoreFoundation                  0x31efe930 parseXMLElement + 2760
    8   CoreFoundation                  0x31efdc8e getContentObject + 450
    9   CoreFoundation                  0x31efe6aa parseXMLElement + 2114
    10  CoreFoundation                  0x31efdc8e getContentObject + 450
    11  CoreFoundation                  0x31efe6aa parseXMLElement + 2114
    12  CoreFoundation                  0x31efdc8e getContentObject + 450
    13  CoreFoundation                  0x31efe1c4 parseXMLElement + 860
    14  CoreFoundation                  0x31f0a044 _CFPropertyListCreateFromUTF8Data + 1592
    15  CoreFoundation                  0x31edcfb6 _CFPropertyListCreateWithData + 882
    16  CoreFoundation                  0x31edcbe0 CFPropertyListCreateFromXMLData + 116
    17  Foundation                      0x328114ea +[NSDictionary(NSDictionary) newWithContentsOf:immutable:] + 110
    18  Sparkle                         0x006c4f66 -[Environments initializeSharedInstance] (Environments.m:38)
    19  Sparkle                         0x006c4d54 +[Environments sharedInstance] (Environments.m:27)
    20  Sparkle                         0x006c4992 +[ConfigurationManager getLogLevel:] (ConfigurationManager.m:54)
    21  Sparkle                         0x006c4870 +[ConfigurationManager logLevelForFileName:] (ConfigurationManager.m:21)
    22  Sparkle                         0x006e824a -[NTRequestPolicy init] (NTRequestPolicy.m:38)
    23  Sparkle                         0x006e80f6 +[NTRequestPolicy sharedRequestPolicy] (NTRequestPolicy.m:24)
    24  Sparkle                         0x004f5fe8 +[WAGServiceHandler execute:requestObject:responseClass:serviceCallBack:requestType:additionalHTTPHeaders:backgroundRequest:] (WAGServiceHandler.m:39)
    25  Sparkle                         0x004f5ed0 +[WAGServiceHandler execute:requestObject:responseClass:serviceCallBack:requestType:] (WAGServiceHandler.m:26)
    26  Sparkle                         0x004f5e72 +[WAGServiceHandler execute:requestObject:responseClass:serviceCallBack:] (WAGServiceHandler.m:20)
    27  Sparkle                         0x0040acaa -[Mbox load] (Mbox.m:118)
    28  Sparkle                         0x0040bf52 -[MBoxHandler invokeMboxManager] (MBoxHandler.m:47)
    29  Sparkle                         0x0040d548 __39-[MomentumMapPlugIn downloadIconImages]_block_invoke (MomentumMapPlugIn.m:222)
    30  libdispatch.dylib               0x3a03111c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8
    31  libdispatch.dylib               0x3a030996 _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$up + 142
    32  libdispatch.dylib               0x3a030890 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$up + 32
    33  libdispatch.dylib               0x3a03f212 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 190
    34  libdispatch.dylib               0x3a03f3b4 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 80
    35  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a065a0e _pthread_wqthread + 358
    36  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a0658a0 start_wqthread + 4
```

Comment: you say that the crash doesn't happen all the time. Have you checked all the crash logs to see if the device and OS version are the same each time. The log above says it is an iPod running iOS 6.1.3 if it is always on the same device and iOS combination then it would probably be worth getting that device and iOS version to test and debug on

Comment: @AdamRichardson Yes i tested in iPod but iOS 6.0.1 version. Even i am unable to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, Exception Type 20 means you are doing asynchronous networking on the main thread and when the connection or operation is slow, the App can be terminated by iOS. This will occur randomly. See this note:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1693/_index.html

Answer (score 2):

If you get `Exception Type: 00000020` and `Exception Codes: 0x8badf00d` in your crash log then it is **Watchdog time out crash report.**

This happens when you *execute activity synchronously on main thread.*
Fix for this is to *use asynchronously on main thread.*

[image: Screenshot for this error]

This [Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1693/_index.html) provides detail about this crash in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing modify your code like that below and test.

```
    if([[NSFileManager DefaultManger] 
      fileExistAtPath:envsPListPath]){
     NSDictionary *environments = [[NSDictionary
    dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:envsPListPath];
    }
```

Comment: Anyway i am unable to reproduce the issue but for safety i can write this code. thanks for help.

Comment: Will it get crash if the path is empty ?

Comment: Yes this for safety purpose if filename will not exist then definetly it will throw exception and also increase the probablity of crash. If you do the testing using some tool and if filename is empty then you can easily see the crash

Comment: Yes i tested by giving empty string. It was crashing . but the crash log is different from what i posted here. It means both crashes are different .

Comment: Yes thats what if condition i have used so that if found empty then it will not crash.

Answer (score 0):

Find in which thread your app is crashing and put that thread in

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // run that crashing thread here.
    });
});
```